# Jenkins not recognizing git binary

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed git successfully on Centos 5.7,

$ git --version
git version 1.7.4.1

While pulling the source from the github from jenkins, i am facing following issue

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=2, No such file or directory
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:709)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:338)
at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:345)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:774)
```

Jenkins not recognizing git binary.

please help me on this

Answer (score 5):

You can also override the git path on a per-node basis. Just go to the configure page of your node, and check `Tool Locations`, and provide the git path on that system.

Here on OSX, it was `/usr/local/git/bin/git` for me. You can determine it by executing `which git` as jenkins user on your node.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins needs to know where your git binary file is installed; this is usually at /usr/bin/git on Linux systems.  Go to the /configure page of your Jenkins installation (the "Manage Jenkins" link) and set it up in the "Git" section.

Comment: while i am trying to configure, i am facing issue "There's no such executable git in PATH: /sbin, /usr/sbin, /bin, /usr/bin."

Comment: Try typing "which git" to find the path.  Just to make sure, did you install Git on the same machine that is running Jenkins ?

Comment: yes .. i did .. git present in the /usr/bin/git.. and i have created symbolic link to /sbin /bin .. but no luck ..